# url doesn't work after splitting it using splitTextToSize() in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a very big URL which I splitted using the method below in **jsPDF**:

```
   var finalY=20;

   doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);

   doc.text(30,finalY,"APDJ");

   finalY+=2;

   doc.line(30,finalY,190,finalY);

   doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255);

   for(var j=0; j<social_neg[i].length; j++){ //social_neg[] is a string of urls fetched from php server

       if(social_neg[i][j].length>60){

           var url = doc.splitTextToSize(social_neg[i][j],140);

           finalY+=20;

       }
       else{

           var url = social_neg[i][j];

           finalY+=15;

       }

       doc.text(40,finalY,url);

   }

   finalY+=20;

   doc.line(30,finalY,190,finalY);
```

My pdf:

[Only the first line is clickable, the rest are not. Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoVS4.jpg)

As you can see, the first line of the url is clickable, the rest of the url isn't. Why is that? How do I fix this?

Comment: I have tried the same url which you have mwntioned, and when I clicked in pdf, it worked. Please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: @Aditya, I have updated the code, please have a look